# Algorithm for calculating position numbers for nested list elements

Tags: algorithm, tree, nested

Hi I am working with nested setes, I have some elements with `level`, `parent`, `left` and `right` fields. I have to calculate numbers representing element position in a whole set.

Something like this:

```
1. a
  1.1. b
  1.2. c
  1.3. d
    1.3.1. e
    1.3.2. f
2. g
  2.1. h
```

Any ideas for the algorithm?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard - a recursive function with a loop in it, or something similar. Show your data structure, please.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have your items stored in a dictionary/hashmap, keyed by the item's id ("a", "b", ...). If you have `parent` and `left` as properties, then values for `level` and `right` are implied, so I'll limit myself to objects with only `parent` and `left` properties. These have as value an id ("a", "b", ...) with which the corresponding item can be looked up in the dictionary.

So the data could look like this (using JSON syntax):

```
{
    "a": { "parent": null, "left": null },
    "b": { "parent": "a",  "left": null },
    "c": { "parent": "a",  "left": "b"  },
    "d": { "parent": "a",  "left": "c"  },
    "e": { "parent": "d",  "left": null },
    "f": { "parent": "d",  "left": "e"  },
    "g": { "parent": null, "left": "a"  },
    "h": { "parent": "g",  "left": null },
}
```

The idea is to use recursion to resolve the numbering for the node at the left (if it exists), and then we can copy that numbering and increment the last part of it.

If there is no left node, then we use recursion to find the numbering of the parent node (if it has one), and then we can copy that numbering and append a 1 to it.

If there is neither a left, neither a parent node, then we know that this item must have 1 as its numbering.

To ease the processing, I have not used a string representation (like "1.3.2"), but an array of numbers ([1, 3, 2]).

Here is a JavaScript implementation:

```js
function resolve(node) {
    if ("heading" in node) return; // already numbered
    if (node.left != null) {
        let left = data[node.left];
        resolve(left);
        node.heading = left.heading.slice(); // copy
        node.heading[node.heading.length - 1]++;
    } else if (node.parent != null) {
        let parent = data[node.parent];
        resolve(parent);
        node.heading = parent.heading.slice(); // copy
        node.heading.push(1);
    } else {
        node.heading = [1];
    }
}

function addHeadings(data) {
    for (let node of Object.values(data)) resolve(node);
}

// Sample data
let data = {
    "a": { parent: null, left: null },
    "b": { parent: "a", left: null },
    "c": { parent: "a", left: "b" },
    "d": { parent: "a", left: "c" },
    "e": { parent: "d", left: null },
    "f": { parent: "d", left: "e" },
    "g": { parent: null, left: "a" },
    "h": { parent: "g", left: null },
};
addHeadings(data); // add heading properties
console.log(data); // show result
```